# How to update all values except one in Realtime Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

This is my node structure:
[image: Database node]
I want to change `email`, `name` and `roll`. For this, I have used `map` in java and used `setvalue(map)`. But the problem is node `extra` is being deleted here. This node is used by cloud function, so I don't want to download the data and set the data while saving again.
Because:
[image: Reason for not downloading]
If the above step is completed before the below step, then I won't get the URL.
**I don't want to touch the node `extra`** and change other nodes at once. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Why can't read the data as a first step, modify whatever you need, and insert the modified data back into DB?

Comment: I have edited my question. Check the last part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to update all values except one in Realtime Database?

Simply by using [DatabaseReference#updateChildren(Map<String, Object> update)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#updateChildren(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)) and passing a Map object that contains **only** the fields you want to update. In this way, all the other fields will remain untouched.

[DatabaseReference#setValue(Object value)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#setValue(java.lang.Object)) will always overwrite the data at the specific location.